# Я знаю, что(,) если я не приду, тогда она ко мне придёт

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я знаю, что(,) если я не приду, **тогда** она ко мне придёт.

Comment: А какие проблемы? Здесь двойной союз (ЕСЛИ...ТОГДА, ЕСЛИ...ТО), в таких случае запятая на стыке союзов не ставится. Известное правило.

Comment: Я знаю что: если я не приду - тогда она ко мне придёт!

Comment: ИЗВЕСТНОЕ ПРАВИЛО:    Розенталь, пункт 1. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140   Таким образом, при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза то, так или но, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и НЕ СТАВИТСЯ, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть ДВОЙНОГО СОЮЗА .